# img are not displayed correctly in chrome in windows

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, windows-11

`img` tags come with some weird margins in Chrome (same on: Edge and Opera) however Firefox works as expected.

#### Questions

1. What's causing these margins in Chrome? Devtool shows no margin.
2. Is there a simple fix?

#### Code Example

Code Pen Link: https://codepen.io/silwalanish/pen/vYjYVbL

```css
.container {
  gap: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.card {
  border: 2px solid;
}

.thumbnail {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1655427565427-34ea63c7ede6?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8fHx8fHx8MTY2MjE4OTQ4Ng&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=1080" alt="Test Image">
    </div>
    <p>Asdasdasd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1655427565427-34ea63c7ede6?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8fHx8fHx8MTY2MjE4OTQ4Ng&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=1080" alt="Test Image">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1655427565427-34ea63c7ede6?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8fHx8fHx8MTY2MjE4OTQ4Ng&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=1080">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Screenshot

##### Chrome

[image: img with margin]

As you can see the margins on the left and top of the images.

[image: img with margin three sides]

What's even weird is the margins will appear on the right (middle img) if you resize the page.

##### Firefox

[image: img with no margin]

### Edit

This problem only exists on windows. It's working on Linux and as per one of the comment it's working on Mac as well.

No margins in Firefox.

Comment: What you describe doesn't happen here, neither in Chrome nor in Opera (on Mac)

Comment: Maybe some zooming (and rounding) issue in your browser?

Comment: @Johannes Is there any settings that you know I can change? Or any keywords I should be searching for?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to remove the default margin and padding on the body. Some browsers add them by default. Hope this helps.
`body{ margin:0; padding: 0; }`

Comment: I am not talking about the margins outside the cards. And no this doesn't work. I've also tried setting the margins and padding to zero for all elements.. Thanks anyways.